# In my application in iOS i need to show the default 5 users when enters in to that particular screen

Tags: ios, parsing, xml-parsing

I am designing a application in that application i have a View controller named SearchViewController, in that i can search the other users from my application. The users are available from a service.

The main task is that i need to show default 5 users on load when i enters this view controller, the default 5 users are there in the service itself, i just need to call the service from my application and from that view controller. I am new to this iOS development, and the data is in the form of XML in the services, How to parse this XML data to my application.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: you should learn how to parse xml. there are many questions in SO and tutorials. please read this doc (http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/08/parsing-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html). you have to change your question title to how to parse xml?. i think your question is about parsing xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st declare variables as

```
    NSMutableURLRequest             *req;
    NSURLConnection                 *conn;
    NSMutableData                   *webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone;
```

in .h file then Using `NSURLConnection` delegate methods you can set connection & get data from service as follow:-

```
NSString *str_url = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xmlWebservicesUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_url];
req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone  = [NSMutableData data] ;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   [webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   [webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error
{
   NSLog(@"error...................%@",[error description]);

   [delegate processMerchantLoginAndProfileData:@"error" success:0];

   alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You are not connected to the internet. Please check your internet connection and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];

   return;
}

 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{ 
    //Check the request and returns the response.
    //NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes get iphone Data: %d", [webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone length]);
   theXMLMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithBytes: [webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone mutableBytes]
                              length: [webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone length]
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   //---shows the XML---

   (@"shows the XML %@",theXMLMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone);

   if(xmlParserMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone)
   {
      xmlParserMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone];
      [xmlParserMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone setDelegate: self];
      [xmlParserMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
      [xmlParserMerchantLoginAndProfileDataIphone parse];    
   }
}
```

Thenn there are delegate methods for xml arsing as below

```
//---when the start of an element is found---
-(void)  parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI  qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName  attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
}
```

where u can parse xml according to response what u get